# How include SEO in Angular 2 so google can index my site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

How can we apply google indexing for our angular 2 SPA.
we are working on angular 2 on our site and our links like 'http://exammple.com/#/en/logs'.

How we can include SEO in this situation?
How we can include meta data according to route?
We are using MVC & Web Api in backend.

Please Advise.

Comment: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-universal-meet-the-internet-of-the-future-seo-friendly-single-page-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain JS (or TS) to update the DOM

[4.0.0-beta.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/2.3.0...4.0.0-beta.0) also provides a `Meta` service, that you can use for that purpose. (similar to the `Title` service but for setting `<meta>` tags)

Comment: yes , but meta will be inserted in client side , how google will use them for indexing ? google dose not know when the page rendering finish

Comment: You wrote "meta data according to route". How should this work with server-side? Perhaps you want to use Angular-Universal for server-side rendering.